# How can I use dynamic rulesets to redirect and modify the headers of the same request using Chrome's declarativeNetRequest APIs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I have been working on a Chrome extension for shared internal use to facilitate local development; as such, I need to achieve two separate things on the same request:

1. Redirect an XHR from a public domain (specified by the user) to another domain (also specified by the user). Note that since these are defined by the user, **I must use dynamic rulesets**
2. Add an additional header to the redirected request

Unfortunately, I am having trouble achieving either of the following with Chrome's `declarativeNetRequest` APIs:

1. Apply two different rules (in this case, `modifyHeaders` and `redirect`) for the same request, OR
2. Redirect the request with one rule, and have a second rule match with the "new" (redirected) request.

Can this behaviour be achieved in any way?

For all attempts, here are the relevant segments of my `manifest.json` (please note that while I work on this, I'm relaxing my permissions, like `host_permissions` below, as much as possible):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "storage"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Request Redirector",
    "default_popup": "index.html" 
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "rewrite.js"
  }
}
```

And here are code snippets for my dynamic rules:

**RULE 1**

```
const getBaseRedirectRule = (redirectDomain = '', initialDomain = '') => {
  return {
    id: 1,
    priority: 1,
    action: { 
      type: "redirect",
      redirect: {
        regexSubstitution: `https://${redirectDomain}/\\1`
      },
    },
    condition: {
      regexFilter: `^https://${initialDomain.replaceAll('.', '\\.')}/(.*)`,
    }
  }
}
```

So an example with substituted inputs is:

```
{
  id: 1,
  priority: 1,
  action: { 
    type: "redirect",
    redirect: {
      regexSubstitution: "https://localhost.subdomain.com:8443/\\1"
    },
  },
  condition: {
    regexFilter: `^https://public\\.subdomain\\.com/graphql`,
  }
}
```

**RULE 2**

```
const getBaseWriteHeaderRule = (operation = "set", value = '', redirectDomain = '') => {
  return {
    id: 2,
    priority: 1,
    action: {
      type: "modifyHeaders",
      requestHeaders: [{
        header: "authorization",
        operation,
        value,
      }]
    },
    condition: {
      urlFilter: `${redirectDomain}/*`
    },
  }
}
```

So an example with substituted inputs is:

```
{
  id: 2,
  priority: 1,
  action: {
    type: "modifyHeaders",
    requestHeaders: [{
      header: "authorization",
      operation: "set",
      value: "my-auth-value",
    }]
  },
  condition: {
    urlFilter: `localhost.subdomain.com:8443/*`
  },
}
```

I have confirmed using `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug` that these rules, when applied individually, **do indeed work**, so there is no issue with my `regexFilter` or `urlFilter` conditions. However, when used in tandem, **the second rule is not applied, I presume because it is a redirected request and not one initiated by the document itself**.

If I take the second rule above and attempt to modify the headers of the request to the `initialDomain` from the first rule instead (`public.subdomain.com` in the first rule's example), it will only select ONE of the rules (the redirect), which is as the `declarativeNetRequest` API is designed.

Is there any way to both redirect a request and modify the request headers to the new endpoint?

Comment: It's likely https://crbug.com/1247400. Use an external tool like Fiddler/Charles/WireShark to verify the presence of the header. P.S. Instead of regex, which is super inefficient, use requestDomains in condition and [transform](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#property-Redirect-transform) in action.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment - however I have confirmed that for request headers, they do indeed apply/show up, and thus this bug does not appear to apply in this case (which is only for response headers). I will play around with the requestDomains though, thanks :)

Comment: Just because the report describes one case doesn't mean the same underlying problem doesn't apply to another case. BTW it may be a limitation of the API, maybe it can't apply multiple rules to one request.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, I have confirmed that request headers do get appended in isolation so that bug is indeed not applicable here.
You've also gotten to the crux of my question - I'm hoping to find out if this is:
A) A limitation of the API, or
B) Possible, and if so, how

Comment: What if the bug manifests only in some cases? To investigate what happens you need to establish the facts and not logical constructions based on inference. Anyway, the API would greatly benefit from the ability to declare multiple actions in one rule, so consider opening a feature request on https://crbug.com.